# lua_pcall cause "cannot resume dead coroutine"

Tags: lua

i have such c++ code below to call lua code

```
for (int i =0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    lua_getglobal(g_L, "AnalyzeScript");
    lua_pushstring(g_L, "1");
    lua_pushstring(g_L, "2");
    lua_pushstring(g_L, "3");

    if(lua_pcall(g_L,3,0,0) != 0)
    {
        //          char temp[200]={0}; sprintf(temp, "err: %s",  lua_tostring(g_L, -1));
        //          MessageBoxA(0,temp,0,0);
    }
```

lua code like below

```
local cnt = 0
function AnalyzeScript(foldername, filename, pOut)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    print(cnt)
end
```

every thing is ok, except "cannot resume dead coroutine"(which coroutine is in another place)

it looks like that 2000 times to call lua func ruin the lua stack, if i change 2000 to 200, every goes ok!

why?

Comment: What is "the coroutine"? Can you give us [enough code to be able to see this happen](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: i know my quest is not enough, exactly i called the for in a hook function, which function execute in timer, i can't give a exactly describe about what the function is because i don't think it's special

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error.  I've changed the code a little:

```
/* test.c */
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

void main() {
    int i;
    lua_State *g_L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(g_L);
    luaL_dofile(g_L, "s.lua");
    for (i =0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        lua_getglobal(g_L, "AnalyzeScript");
        lua_pushstring(g_L, "1");
        lua_pushstring(g_L, "2");
        lua_pushstring(g_L, "3");

        if(lua_pcall(g_L,3,0,0) != 0)
        {
//          char temp[200]={0}; sprintf(temp, "err: %s",  lua_tostring(g_L, -1));
//          MessageBoxA(0,temp,0,0);
        }
    }
    lua_close (g_L);
}
```

It was compiled in my Linux with the following command (I have Lua distribution installed in /fakepath/lua-5.2.0):

```
gcc test.c -I/fakepath/lua-5.2.0/src /fakepath/lua-5.2.0/src/liblua.a -lm -ldl
```

File test.lua is exactly what you've posted.
Maybe the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: i know my quest is not enough, exactly i called the for in a hook function, which function execute in timer, i can't give a exactly describe about what the function is because i don't think it's special